# Load new JSON data and replace the old one in VueJS

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I'm using a v-for loop with data fetched from JSON file. Is there a way to re-render the DOM and whole v-for loop after loading a new JSON file and replacing the old one?
What I'm trying to achieve is load different sets of products on click and update DOM.

```
Vue.use(VueResource);    
var productsList = new Vue({
    el: '#vue',
    data: function () {
        return {
            products: []
        };
    },
    ready: function () {
        this.$http.get('data/data.json').then(function (response) {
            this.products = response.data;
        });
    },
    methods: {
        loadProducts: function (url) {
            this.$http.get(url).then(function (response) {
                this.products = response.data;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The code above should be sufficient for updating your DOM automatically. There are 2 errors however and 1 thing you should consider.

Anonymous functions have different scopes in javascript. This means that when you have an anonymous function `function(response)` then you lose the scope of the vue instance `this`. In order to deal with such situations you have to either use arrow functions if you have support for them in your project or save `this` into another variable before entering the anonymous function.

```
Vue.use(VueResource);    
var productsList = new Vue({
el: '#vue',
data: function () {
    return {
        products: []
    };
},
ready: function () {
    var self=this;
    this.$http.get('data/data.json').then(function (response) {
        self.products = response.data;
    });
},
methods: {
    loadProducts: function (url) {
        var self=this;
        this.$http.get(url).then(function (response) {
            self.products = response.data;
        });
    }
}
});
```

Also if you have this exact code, you should've received an error in browser with products being undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe my question wasn't clear enough. The problem is that when I fetch new "products" from JSON correctly I can see the updates in DOM, but what I'm trying to achieve is to display only the products from new data and remove the old ones from DOM.

Comment: Well by setting `this.products=something` you already tell Vue that you want to place new data in the array and it will re-render the DOM for you with that data. Don't quite get what you want as a visual effect there.

Comment: Yes, that does work. Here's what I mean - initial data1.json has 5 products. If I set "this.products" to data2.json, which has 3 products, DOM displays all 8 products instead of only 3, even though that console shows only 3 objects in products array.

Comment: Well that's strange. It should replace the whole array unless you are not pushing the data to the array. Here is a fiddle showing that https://jsfiddle.net/z11fe07p/489/

Comment: Ok I found where was the problem, but I don't understand why. It works properly now when I removed the transition from the loop items. So not sure why but when I add `transition="stagger" stagger="100"` the old products get the `leave` class but are not removed from DOM.

Answer (score 2):

Once you update the `products` data it will automatically change the DOM as par the latest data, as vue data is reactive. One error I see in your code is, you may have wrong `this` inside the `this.$http` block. instead of using `function()` syntax, use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which does not bind it's own [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), [super](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super), or [new.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target), like following:

```
Vue.use(VueResource);    
var productsList = new Vue({
    el: '#vue',
    data: function () {
        return {
            products: []
        };
    },
    ready: function () {
        this.$http.get('data/data.json').then((response) => {
            this.products = response.data;
        });
    },
    methods: {
        loadProducts: function (url) {
            this.$http.get(url).then( (response) => {
                this.products = response.data;
            });
        }
    }
});
```